# Error when I set a radio button to be checked by default

Tags: vb.net, radio-button, radio-group

I have a radio button in my VB.NET dll that I wan't to be checked by default. There is a total of 3 radio buttons in this group. Under its properties I set Checked = true. I verified the code was there, this is all the form generated code for the radio button:

```
Me.rdbProductPC.AutoSize = True
Me.rdbProductPC.Checked = True
Me.rdbProductPC.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 8.25!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
Me.rdbProductPC.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(49, 12)
Me.rdbProductPC.Name = "rdbProductPC"
Me.rdbProductPC.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(45, 17)
Me.rdbProductPC.TabIndex = 1
Me.rdbProductPC.TabStop = True
Me.rdbProductPC.Text = "P&&C"
Me.rdbProductPC.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
```

For some reason I get this error when I start the application:

> An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details.  The error is: ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.

Nothing has changed besides the one line adjusting the checked value. Any idea what could be causing this?

This is the  code for my GetProducts() method. The error arises after the call to ExecuteReader() but I cannot see the code for this.  If my g_strSQL =  `pc_mis_busunit_product_relate_summary` it executes fine. But when g_strSQL = `pc_mis_busunit_product_relate_summary '','','N'` it errors out.

That being said, if I leave the radio button unchecked by default and then check it later while the program is running it will go into this same method and g_strSQL will look like `pc_mis_busunit_product_relate_summary '','','N'` and it will work fine.

```
Private Sub GetProducts(ByVal ProductList As ListBox)
    Dim g_strSQL As String

    ProductList.Items.Clear()
    lstProductSel.Items.Clear()
    lstProduct.Enabled = True

    g_strSQL = String.Empty


    objcmd.Connection = ControlConnection

    'Clear location combo box
    Select Case intProduct
        Case Product.Summary
            g_strSQL = g_strSQL & "pc_mis_busunit_product_relate_summary "
        Case Product.Detail
            g_strSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT b.dtl_prod_cd, rtrim(ltrim(b.dtl_prod_desc))"
            g_strSQL = g_strSQL & " FROM product_detail_ref b "
            g_strSQL = g_strSQL & " ORDER BY rtrim(ltrim(b.dtl_prod_desc)) "
        Case Else
            Exit Sub
    End Select

    If p_and_C <> String.Empty Then
        g_strSQL = g_strSQL & "'" & String.Empty & "','" & String.Empty & "','" & p_and_C & "'"
    End If

    If g_strSQL <> "" Then
        objcmd.CommandText = g_strSQL
        rsProducts = objcmd.ExecuteReader()
    End If

    'Process results from query

    If rsProducts.HasRows = False Then
        rsProducts.Close()
        Exit Sub
    Else
        ' This nested if will check which radio button is selected and add the corresponding
        ' 'all' entry to the top of the lstProduct box
        If rdbProductPC.Checked = True Then
            ProductList.Items.Add(PAndCConstants.ALL_P_AND_C)
        ElseIf rdbProductNonPC.Checked = True Then
            ProductList.Items.Add(PAndCConstants.ALL_NON_P_AND_C)
        Else
            ProductList.Items.Add(PAndCConstants.ALL)
        End If

        ProductList.SelectedIndex = 0
        While rsProducts.Read()
            ProductList.Items.Add(rsProducts(0))
        End While
        ProductList.SetSelected(0, True)
        rsProducts.Close()
    End If

    rsProducts = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you post your form_load code for that form?

Comment: Somewhere else it seems your trying to query for data and its erroring somewhere, this is not related to your radiobuttons at all. Hint: execute reader is your issue, if you post what you have maybe we can help.

Comment: I don't have the code for executeReader() but I posted some other code I think might have something to do with it.